# FedEx XML Api Tracking Request Issues

Tags: php, xml, fedex

I'm attempting to implement FedEx Package Tracking in a project using the XML api. The following is my tracking request:

```
'<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v6="http://fedex.com/ws/track/v6">
                <soapenv    '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v6="http://fedex.com/ws/track/v6">
                <soapenv:Header/>
                <soapenv:Body>
                <v6:TrackRequest>
                    <v6:WebAuthenticationDetail>
                        <v6:UserCredential>
                            <v6:Key>'.fedex_accesskey.'</v6:Key>
                            <v6:Password>'.fedex_password.'</v6:Password>
                        </v6:UserCredential>
                    </v6:WebAuthenticationDetail>
                    <v6:ClientDetail>
                        <v6:AccountNumber>'.fedex_account.'</v6:AccountNumber>
                        <v6:MeterNumber>'.fedex_meter.'</v6:MeterNumber>
                        <v6:IntegratorId></v6:IntegratorId>
                        <v6:Localization>
                            <v6:LanguageCode>EN</v6:LanguageCode>
                            <v6:LocaleCode>US</v6:LocaleCode>
                        </v6:Localization>
                    </v6:ClientDetail>
                    <v6:TransactionDetail>
                        <v6:CustomerTransactionId>Track By Number</v6:CustomerTransactionId>
                        <v6:Localization>
                        <v6:LanguageCode>EN</v6:LanguageCode>
                        <v6:LocaleCode>US</v6:LocaleCode>
                        </v6:Localization>
                    </v6:TransactionDetail>
                    <v6:Version>
                        <v6:ServiceId>trck</v6:ServiceId>
                        <v6:Major>6</v6:Major>
                        <v6:Intermediate>0</v6:Intermediate>
                        <v6:Minor>0</v6:Minor>
                    </v6:Version>
                    <v6:PackageIdentifier>
                        <v6:Value>'.$tracking_number.'</v6:Value>
                        <v6:Type>TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG</v6:Type>
                    </v6:PackageIdentifier>
                </v6:TrackRequest>
                </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>';:Header/>
                <soapenv:Body>
                <v6:TrackRequest>
                    <v6:WebAuthenticationDetail>
                        <v6:UserCredential>
                            <v6:Key>'.fedex_accesskey.'</v6:Key>
                            <v6:Password>'.fedex_password.'</v6:Password>
                        </v6:UserCredential>
                    </v6:WebAuthenticationDetail>
                    <v6:ClientDetail>
                        <v6:AccountNumber>'.fedex_account.'</v6:AccountNumber>
                        <v6:MeterNumber>'.fedex_meter.'</v6:MeterNumber>
                        <v6:IntegratorId></v6:IntegratorId>
                        <v6:Localization>
                            <v6:LanguageCode>EN</v6:LanguageCode>
                            <v6:LocaleCode>US</v6:LocaleCode>
                        </v6:Localization>
                    </v6:ClientDetail>
                    <v6:TransactionDetail>
                        <v6:CustomerTransactionId>Track By Number</v6:CustomerTransactionId>
                        <v6:Localization>
                        <v6:LanguageCode>EN</v6:LanguageCode>
                        <v6:LocaleCode>US</v6:LocaleCode>
                        </v6:Localization>
                    </v6:TransactionDetail>
                    <v6:Version>
                        <v6:ServiceId>trck</v6:ServiceId>
                        <v6:Major>6</v6:Major>
                        <v6:Intermediate>0</v6:Intermediate>
                        <v6:Minor>0</v6:Minor>
                    </v6:Version>
                    <v6:PackageIdentifier>
                        <v6:Value>'.$tracking_number.'</v6:Value>
                        <v6:Type>TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG</v6:Type>
                    </v6:PackageIdentifier>
                </v6:TrackRequest>
                </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>';
```

All values are being swapped in correctly, and I am getting a success response back from FedEx. The issue is the response only has one tracking event. The event appears to be the last tracking update from FedEx (in this case, delivery time, date, and address) but is not showing any tracking events along the way.

Here is the response I get: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3jcFwPnm)

As you can see, the package status is delivered, and the delivery address is listed in , but the origin and the steps along the way are not. Any suggestions on how to get all the tracking info and not just the most recent step? Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing to set to **true** the **IncludeDetailedScans** element. Here is an example of a SOAP Envelope:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <TrackRequest xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/track/v6">
      <WebAuthenticationDetail>
        <CspCredential>
          <Key>CSP_KEY</Key>
          <Password>CSP_PASSWORD</Password>
        </CspCredential>
        <UserCredential>
          <Key>DEVELOPER_KEY</Key>
          <Password>DEVELOPER_PASSWORD</Password>
        </UserCredential>
      </WebAuthenticationDetail>
      <ClientDetail>
        <AccountNumber>ACCOUNT_NUMBER</AccountNumber>
        <MeterNumber>METER_NUMBER</MeterNumber>
        <ClientProductId>CLIENT_PRODUCT_ID</ClientProductId>
        <ClientProductVersion>CLIENT_PRODUCT_VERSION</ClientProductVersion>
      </ClientDetail>
      <Version>
        <ServiceId>trck</ServiceId>
        <Major>6</Major>
        <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
        <Minor>0</Minor>
      </Version>
      <PackageIdentifier>
        <Value>TRACKING_NUMBER</Value>
        <Type>TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG</Type>
      </PackageIdentifier>
      <IncludeDetailedScans>true</IncludeDetailedScans>
    </TrackRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Note that the previous request is only valid if you belong to the FedEx CSP program, if you don't, the code below is the right one for your:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <TrackRequest xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/track/v6">
      <WebAuthenticationDetail>
        <UserCredential>
          <Key>DEVELOPER_KEY</Key>
          <Password>DEVELOPER_PASSWORD</Password>
        </UserCredential>
      </WebAuthenticationDetail>
      <ClientDetail>
        <AccountNumber>ACCOUNT_NUMBER</AccountNumber>
        <MeterNumber>METER_NUMBER</MeterNumber>
      </ClientDetail>
      <Version>
        <ServiceId>trck</ServiceId>
        <Major>6</Major>
        <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
        <Minor>0</Minor>
      </Version>
      <PackageIdentifier>
        <Value>TRACKING_NUMBER</Value>
        <Type>TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG</Type>
      </PackageIdentifier>
      <IncludeDetailedScans>true</IncludeDetailedScans>
    </TrackRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Best!

Answer (score 2):

For Version 8, you need to add the following tag, almost at the very bottom of the XML request, right above the closing "TrackRequest" tag:

```
<ProcessingOptions>INCLUDE_DETAILED_SCANS</ProcessingOptions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution hidden in the FedEx documentation. It is to supply 1 to get the full history. This value defaults to false and omits all that important tracking information.

Comment: Please provide a reference to that documentation, e.g. link that information.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question wasn't geared towards .NET but if anyone arrives here (like I did) looking for a .NET specific answer to this question, here it is:

```
Dim request As New TrackRequest()
Dim options(0) As TrackRequestProcessingOptionType

options(0) = TrackRequestProcessingOptionType.INCLUDE_DETAILED_SCANS
request.ProcessingOptions = options
```